# Как увеличить область триггера NavigationView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, layout, lib

Меня очень заинтересовала библиотека https://github.com/mxn21/FlowingDrawer.
Все бы хорошо но мне не нравиться маленькая область триггера при котором раскрывается FlowingMenuLayout(NavigationView).В нативном NavigationView все вроде бы понятно, это можно реализовать методом рефлексии.

```
Field mDragger = null;
    try {
        mDragger = mm.getClass().getDeclaredField(
                "mLeftDragger");  //Как я понял это переменная внутри DrawerLayout класса отвечающая за область тригера.
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mDragger.setAccessible(true);
    ViewDragHelper draggerObj = null;
    try {
        draggerObj = (ViewDragHelper) mDragger
                .get(mm);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Field mEdgeSize = null;
    try {
        mEdgeSize = draggerObj.getClass().getDeclaredField(
                "mEdgeSize");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mEdgeSize.setAccessible(true);
    int edge = 0;
    try {
        edge = mEdgeSize.getInt(draggerObj);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        mEdgeSize.setInt(draggerObj, edge * 5);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Может кто подскажет, как добиться того же, но только в этой библиотеки с FlowingMenuLayout. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось гораздо проще атрибут app:edTouchBezelSize="150dp" в FlowingDrawer влияет на это.